# Compare the result of a date function with a date literal in a WHERE clause

Tags: soql

The below query is not working:

```
SELECT Id
FROM OrderItem
WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH(Order.EffectiveDate) = THIS_MONTH
AND CALENDAR_YEAR(Order.EffectiveDate) = THIS_YEAR
```

I am getting the following error message:

> INVALID_FIELD: WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH(Order.EffectiveDate) = THIS_MONTH
>   ^ ERROR at Row:3:Column:22 value of filter criterion for expression
>   CALENDAR_MONTH(EffectiveDate) must be of type integer and should not
>   be enclosed in quotes

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do either:

```
CALENDAR_MONTH(Field__c) = 7
```

or:

```
Field__c = THIS_MONTH
```

You want the latter.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Adrian's answer, the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm) explains that:

> You can't compare the result of a date function with a date literal in
>   a WHERE clause. The following query doesn't work:

```
SELECT CreatedDate, Amount
FROM Opportunity
WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) = THIS_YEAR
```

hence the need for a workaround where you have to add a field containing the month.

Answer (score 3):

Please explore [Date Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm) for SOQL. CALENDAR_MONTH() returns a value of the Integer type, whereas THIS_MONTH (see [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)) is a String literal.

So basically what you get in the runtime for `CALENDAR_MONTH(Order.EffectiveDate) = THIS_MONTH` is (don't mind the actual values, they are for the example's sake only):

```
7 = '2005-10-08T01:02:03Z'
```

So you need to follow Adrian's advice.

Answer (score 1):

CALENDAR_MONTH/CALENDA_YEAR returns a number. Here, you are trying to compare a number to a date, that is why, it throws an error.